# ChromeDriver reiniciando em todos os testes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, testes-automatizados

Seguindo um tutorial, a minha página de stepDefinitions está assim:

```
@RunWith(DataDrivenTestRunner.class)
@DataLoader(filePaths = "credenciaisv2.csv")

public class CadastrarOLTTest {
    private  WebDriver browser;


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        browser = Server.createBrowser();
    }

    @Test
    public void CadastrarOLTv2Test(@Param(name="ip") String ip,
                                   @Param(name="user") String user,
                                   @Param(name="password") String senha,
                                   @Param(name="enable") String enable){
        new Login(browser).digitaLogin("admin").insereCredenciaisV2(ip, user, senha, enable);
    }
}
```

Com o `DataDrivenTestRunner.class` pretendo executar o método `insereCredenciaisV2` utilizando as credenciais presentes no arquivo `credenciaisv2.csv`

Ocorre que ele está executando o `@Before` a cada repetição do `@Test` com novos parâmetros, e criando novas instâncias de navegador a cada teste. Como isso pode ser contornado?

Comment: qual a versão do junit, a 5? se não for o que você precisa utilizar é o @beforeclass

Comment: o problema é que dai o meu método setUp() vai precisar ser estático e causa transtornos.